# How do I assign a colour to this part only

Tags: modeling, color

I need to assign a color to this part:
[image]

But when I assign it, this happens:
[image]

How do I make it go only in the selected area?
heres the full image if it helps:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to BSE,

You appear to have overlapping faces. The faces to which you are attempting to add color are overlapping with other faces from your model.

If you can provide you .blend file I can provide more advice on how to fix this, but for now I would suggest introducing a separate mesh into your model (i.e. Shift+A > Mesh > UV Sphere), and apply the new color to the new mesh.

Comment: I have no idea how to do the separate mesh method
So um how do I provide the file? Or how do I do the separate mesh?

Comment: Nevermind, one of my friends told me just to apply the modifier and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Your *Subdivision Surface* modifier will deform the shape of your faces and therefore the shape of your moon. You'd better use a PNG image as a mask in your material:

[image]

If you don't want to use this method I guess you need to work the topology until it gives the desired result (you can use a copy of your object as the target of a *Shrinkwrap* modifier so that the shape stays the same):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying, I would but I need to follow the concept exactly, and I would just mess up the mask